# Using PHP functions with MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I have a PHP function like:

```
function insert_data($key, $value) {
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO table (key, value) VALUES (:key, :value)');
  $params = [
     ':key' => $key,
     ':value' => $value
  ];
  $stmt->execute($params);
}
```

I then call this function several times in my code:

```
$name = insert_data('Name', 'Joe');
$email = insert_data('Email', 'example@example.com');
```

However, I'd like to make sure that if one transaction fails, it doesn't commit everything else. Will placing $dbh->beginTransaction(); before I call the function and $dbh->commit(); after the function work, or do I need to do something else?

Comment: As a sidenote: Consider preparing your statement in another function, then passing it to `insert_data`.  That's part of the beauty of prepared statements - you only need to prepare them once, then you can run them multiple times with different parameters.  It'll save on queries passed to the SQL server too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable exceptions, and then use `try/catch` to roll back the transaction if there's a failure.

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    $name = insert_data('Name', 'Joe');
    $email = insert_data('Email', 'example@example.com');
    $dbh->commit();
} except (Exception $e) {
    if ($dbh->inTransaction()) {
        $dbh->rollBack();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not entirely working for me. So while the data doesn't change in the database, I'm not throwing any exceptions. I added an echo "transaction failed"; to see if it would display it, but it didn't either.

Comment: I believe its likely due to the fact my function doesn't return success or not.

Comment: This doesn't care what the function returns.

Comment: I had a mistake in the `setAttribute` line. Try it now.

Comment: Still not working. It looks like the rollback isn't working either because I'm able to get one to insert but the second one to not.

Comment: You're using InnoDB, right? MyISAM doesn't have transactions.